# Are A and B drives reserved by Windows?

Tags: windows, drive, enumerate, floppy

I am doing a hard disk scan in my program, and I remember the bad old days when scanning B drive would freeze my machine. Can I skip A and B drives for those users that still have floppies? Are A or B drives in Windows ever used for things other than a floppy disk?

Comment: Just a quick idea: You could exclude all removable drives.

Comment: The item I am searching for is on a removable drive (a USB stick usually) but never on a floppy.

Comment: This has changed. In the past (e.g. DOS/Windows 98) it was definitely true. However I believe that they can *both* be mapped in Vista+ (if they are not assigned by the FDD driver which would only be if it was entirely disabled, e.g., by BIOS). Run the "Disk Management" snap-in. (I can map B under the Parallels VM, it has a FDD driver for A only.) Due to legacy reasons, only a really silly setup system would utilize A/B for anything else, just as only silly systems change C (although it is entirely possible to have Windows on a different -- non C -- partition).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't matter to you which drive letters are assigned to what kind of drives.

Use [`GetLogicalDrives`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364972.aspx) to determine what drive letters are assigned and [`GetDriveType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939.aspx) and [`SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff551967.aspx) to determine the type of a drive.

Answer (score 2):

Windows always assigns letter A to the first floppy drive, and B to a second floppy drive. If there is no second floppy, B will act as a virtual floppy and will point to A. If there are no floppies, A and B will be considered invalid drive letters.

I believe there is a possibility that if all the drive letters between C and Z are assigned, some old versions of DOS and Windows would reuse A and B, but that's a highly unlikely situation.

Your program can safely skip A and B in its search, assuming you don't care about floppy drives.

**Edit: More info**

Mapped network drives can also inhabit A: and B: